# Google Compute Engine - Start tmux with startup-script

Tags: google-compute-engine, tmux

I'm trying to start a tmux during startup with the metadata key "startup-script". I'm trying to execute `tmux new-session -d -s toto` during the startup, but when I do a `tmux ls` afterwards I don't see any tmux session.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few pre-requisites you might be missing here:

1. The program should be installed on the image. The standard image comes installed with a bare minimal set of programs.
2. The startup script runs every time the instance is started and it runs as `root`. So if you just run `tmux` directly from the startup script, it will start a new `tmux` session but as root user. This is not what you want mostly.

Having said that, this will work (I've given examples using `gcloud` but you can apply the similar logic to REST APIs or the Cloud Console as well):

All of this can be taken care using this startup script:

```
(hash tmux 2>/dev/null || (apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install tmux)) && sudo -H -u USERNAME tmux new-session -d -s toto
```

The above command will install tmux if not already installed and then start a new detached tmux session named `toto`.

You can set this startup script at the time of instance creation:

```
gcloud compute instances create VM_NAME --metadata 'startup-script=(hash tmux 2>/dev/null || (apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install tmux)) && sudo -H -u USERNAME tmux new-session -d -s toto' --zone ZONE_NAME --project PROJECT_NAME
```

or update the metadata anytime later for an existing VM:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata vm-1 --metadata 'startup-script=(hash tmux 2>/dev/null || (apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install tmux)) && sudo -H -u USERNAME tmux new-session -d -s toto' --zone ZONE_NAME --project PROJECT_NAME
```

You can always [re-run the startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript) on the VM (without restarting the VM):

```
$ sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
```

The complete documentation about [Startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) is available here.