# start tmux sessions in googlecloud startup-script

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, startup, tmux, startupscript

I added a startup-script entry in the metadatas of my google cloud instance as suggested in the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)
the question [Google Compute Engine - Start tmux with startup-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524430/google-compute-engine-start-tmux-with-startup-script) didn't work for me.
my startup-script code is:

```
    #! /bin/bash
    tmux start-server
    tmux new -d -s data_vis_pfs 'pachctl mount /var/data_vis/pfs' 
    tmux new -d -s data_vis_server 'cd /var/data_vis/server/ && python ./index.py' 
    tmux new -d -s data_vis_client 'cd /var/data_vis/client/ && npx serve -l 3001 -s build'
```

I also tried :

```
    #! /bin/bash
    tmux start \; \
         new -d -s data_vis_pfs 'pachctl mount /var/data_vis/pfs' \; \
         new -d -s data_vis_server 'cd /var/data_vis/server/ && python ./index.py' \; \
         new -d -s data_vis_client 'cd /var/data_vis/client/ && npx serve -l 3001 -s build'
```

When I do `sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service`; after the machine boots up I get:

```
    Aug 24 12:20:40 work1-cpu systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu GCEMetadataScripts[506]: 2021/08/24 12:20:42 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 20201214.00).
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu GCEMetadataScripts[506]: 2021/08/24 12:20:42 GCEMetadataScripts: Found startup-script in metadata.
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu GCEMetadataScripts[506]: 2021/08/24 12:20:42 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script exit status 0
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu GCEMetadataScripts[506]: 2021/08/24 12:20:42 GCEMetadataScripts: Finished running startup scripts.
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Succeeded.
    Aug 24 12:20:42 work1-cpu systemd[1]: Started Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
```

so it's supposed to be a win (status 0)

But my code doesn't seems to be active (the python server is not launched, the front and the pachctl mount neither). A `top` command doesn't show them too.

I know I am not supposed to see the sessions as it is ran by `root` and I could fix that through Socket but I don't care for the moment: I just need the code to be launched.
Do someone have a clue about what I am missing?

Comment: ah and I did install tmux in the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were various errors. Thanks to [Wojtek_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12257250/wojtek-b) for his detailed answer which led me to the way.

**1 - First problem : dependencies**

I had to install at the start of the script all the needed dependencies, in my case :

**1.1 - system :**

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install -y tmux pachctl nodejs npm python3-setuptools python3.7-dev
```

**1.2 - python :**

```
python3 -m pip install {all packages here....}
```

the list of packages to install was retrieved thanks to a `pip3 list` when logged
note the `python3 -m pip` instead of simply `pip` or `pip3`. This is used if there is a python 2.x in the machine gcloud use 2.x by default and thus this install doesn't work (event pip3 install). Anyway this `python3 -m pip install ...` works I would advise that.

**1.3 - node**

```
npm install -g npx
```

**2 - Tmux :**

```
tmux start \; \
  new -d -s sleep 'sleep 1'\;  \
  new -d -s data_vis_pfs 'export KUBECONFIG=/var/data_vis/.kub/config && gcloud auth activate-service-account pfsmounter@{PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/var/data_vis/sa_cred.json &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt && gcloud container clusters get-credentials {CLUSTER_NAME} --zone={ZONE_NAME} &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt &&  kubectl config current-context &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt && pachctl list repo && pachctl mount /var/data_vis/pfs --verbose &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt' \; \
 new -d -s data_vis_server 'sleep 1 && ls /var/data_vis/pfs/ &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && cd /var/data_vis/server/ && python3 ./index.py &>> /tmp/server_log.txt' \; \
  new -d -s data_vis_client 'cd /var/data_vis/client/ && npx serve -l 3001 -s build &>> /tmp/client_log.txt'
```

- first session sleep : in my case not usefull but seems to be good practice in order for the script not to close too early
- second session pachyderm :

  - I had to create a Service Agent (In the Cloud Console, go to the [service accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?hl=fr&_ga=2.89981467.1680109258.1630487455-166749766.1629713150) or type gcloud service account if dont trust this link)
    with the following authorizations :(sorry if not exact label I had to translate from my language)

    - Reader of cluster Kubernetes Engine
    - Service agent of Kubernetes Engine
    - Reader Kubernetes Engine
  - note the `{CLUSTER_NAME}` `{ZONE_NAME}` (find them through `gcloud container clusters list`) and `{PROJECT}` to replace by your own values. I had to manualy do `export KUBECONFIG=/var/data_vis/.kub/config` otherwise it would fail in the tmux session (although was working in main thread)
- third session : flask server (python) : nothing special, I made a sleep just in case
- fourth session : front application : nothing special

final code :

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install -y tmux pachctl nodejs npm python3-setuptools python3.7-dev 

python3 -m pip install adal aiohttp ansiwrap anyio appdirs argcomplete argon2-cffi arrow asn1crypto async-generator async-timeout attrs backcall backports.functools-lru-cache bidict binaryornot black bleach blinker blis bokeh boto boto3 botocore brotlipy bz2file cachetools catalogue certifi cffi chardet charset-normalizer click cloudpickle colorama colorcet confuse cookiecutter cryptography cycler cymem dask datashader datashape debugpy decorator defusedxml distributed docker docker-pycreds entrypoints fastai fastcore fastprogress Flask Flask-Cors Flask-SocketIO fsspec gcsfs gitdb GitPython google-api-core google-api-python-client google-auth google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-bigquery-storage google-cloud-bigtable google-cloud-core google-cloud-dataproc google-cloud-datastore google-cloud-firestore google-cloud-kms google-cloud-language google-cloud-logging google-cloud-monitoring google-cloud-pubsub google-cloud-scheduler google-cloud-spanner google-cloud-speech google-cloud-storage google-cloud-tasks google-cloud-translate google-cloud-videointelligence google-cloud-vision google-crc32c google-resumable-media googleapis-common-protos grpc-google-iam-v1 grpcio grpcio-gcp h11 HeapDict holoviews htmlmin httplib2 idna ImageHash imageio importlib-metadata ipykernel ipython ipython-genutils ipython-sql ipywidgets itsdangerous jedi Jinja2 jinja2-time jmespath joblib json5 jsonschema jupyter-client jupyter-core jupyter-http-over-ws jupyterlab jupyterlab-git jupyterlab-pygments jupyterlab-server jupyterlab-widgets kiwisolver kubernetes llvmlite locket loguru Markdown MarkupSafe matplotlib matplotlib-inline missingno mistune msgpack multidict multimethod multipledispatch murmurhash mypy-extensions nbclient nbconvert nbdime nbformat nest-asyncio networkx  numba numpy oauthlib olefile packaging pandas pandas-profiling pandocfilters panel papermill param parso partd pathspec pathy patsy pexpect phik pickleshare Pillow pip poyo preshed prettytable prometheus-client prompt-toolkit protobuf psutil ptyprocess pyarrow pyasn1 pyasn1-modules pycosat pycparser pyct pydantic Pygments PyJWT pynndescent pyOpenSSL pyparsing pyrsistent PySocks python-dateutil python-engineio python-pachyderm python-slugify python-socketio pytz pyviz-comms PyWavelets PyYAML pyzmq rawpy regex requests requests-oauthlib requests-unixsocket retrying rope rsa ruamel.yaml ruamel.yaml.clib s3transfer scikit-image scikit-learn scipy seaborn Send2Trash setuptools shellingham simple-websocket simplejson six smart-open smmap sniffio sortedcontainers spacy spacy-legacy SQLAlchemy sqlparse srsly statsmodels tangled-up-in-unicode tblib tenacity terminado testpath text-unidecode textwrap3 thinc threadpoolctl tifffile toml tomli toolz torch torchvision tornado tqdm traitlets typed-ast typeguard typer typing-extensions umap-learn umap-learn[plot]  Unidecode uritemplate urllib3 visions wasabi wcwidth webencodings websocket-client Werkzeug wheel whichcraft widgetsnbextension wrapt wsproto xarray yarl zict zipp 

#pip3 list &>> /tmp/debug1.txt
npm install -g npx
#nodejs --version &>> /tmp/debug1.txt

tmux start \; \
  new -d -s sleep 'sleep 1'\;  \
  new -d -s data_vis_pfs 'export KUBECONFIG=/var/data_vis/.kub/config && gcloud auth activate-service-account pfsmounter@{PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/var/data_vis/sa_cred.json &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt && gcloud container clusters get-credentials {CLUSTER_NAME} --zone={ZONE_NAME} &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt &&  kubectl config current-context &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt && pachctl list repo && pachctl mount /var/data_vis/pfs --verbose &>> /tmp/pfs_log.txt' \; \
  new -d -s data_vis_server 'sleep 1 && ls /var/data_vis/pfs/ &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && cd /var/data_vis/server/ && python3 ./index.py &>> /tmp/server_log.txt' \; \
  new -d -s data_vis_client 'cd /var/data_vis/client/ && npx serve -l 3001 -s build &>> /tmp/client_log.txt'
```

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

**First - depending on the image you're running your machine from - it has to have `tmux` installed**. If it's a new machine with Debian 10 you need to put `sudo apt install tmux -y` at the start of your startup script to install it.

To check if the script ran at the start you can add the `touch /tmp/testfile1.txt` at the end and when the VM has booted up check if the file exists. That's the easies (and not so reliable way to tell if the script ran).

I'm not familiar with `tmux` but I've found out that the server service will exit of there are no sessions created, it looks to me like the server exitx before the new sessions are established. You can try using `sleep 1` [suggested here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/182#issuecomment-281194823) to solve your issue.

I tried running your script as is but had the same results as you, but I did the debugging I mentioned and everything worked;

I added some "debugging" lines to the script and ran it:

```
apt update && sudo apt install tmux -y &>> /tmp/debug1.txt
tmux start-server  &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && echo "--- Line 1 OK" >>/tmp/debug1.txt
tmux new -d -s data_vis_pfs 'pachctl mount /var/data_vis/pfs'  &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && echo "--- Line 2 OK" >>/tmp/debug1.txt
tmux new -d -s data_vis_server 'cd /var/data_vis/server/ && python ./index.py'  &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && echo "--- Line 3 OK" >>/tmp/debug1.txt
tmux new -d -s data_vis_client 'cd /var/data_vis/client/ && npx serve -l 3001 -s build' &>> /tmp/debug1.txt && echo "--- Line 4 OK" >>/tmp/debug1.txt
```

And my result was (I've removed some lines when installing `tmux`):

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libevent-2.1-6 libutempter0

...... removed some lines for better readability ......


Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
--- Line 1 OK
--- Line 2 OK
--- Line 3 OK
--- Line 4 OK
```

**Conclusion: your script ran at the start of the VM.** You just need to figure out how to start tmux sessions & server and then use it as startup script.